# PHPUnit testing a method that changes an entity field

Tags: testing

Let's say I have an entity with certain fields and a method that does the following

```
public function changeEntityField(Entity $entity) {
  $entity->set('field_xyz', 20);
  $entity->save();
  return $entity;
}
```

I know how to mock an entity and set its field values via `$entity->expects($this->any())->method('get')->with('field_xyz')->willReturn(10)` etc. and pass it to the function to be tested.

What I don't get yet is how to test the function does really set the `field_xyz` to 20 ?

I tried

```
$entity = $this->getMockBuilder(Application::class)
  ->disableOriginalConstructor()
  ->getMock();
$field = $this->getMockBuilder(FieldItemListInterface::class)
      ->disableOriginalConstructor()
      ->getMock();
$field->expects($this->any())
      ->method('__get')
      ->with('value')
      ->willReturn(10);
$entity->expects($this->any())
  ->method('get')
  ->with('field_xyz')
  ->willReturn($field);
$result = $this->service->changeEntityField($entity);
$this->assertEqual($result->get('field_xyz')->value, 20);
```

but it returns 10. How do I mock the ->set() methods of the entity? Or do I have to work with real entities and not mocks in such cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that in a **unit test**, you have to work with real entities in a **functional test** since `$entity->save();` needs the database to be loaded.

And as `$result = $this->service->changeEntityField($entity);` will return an entity there's no way `$result` can be equal to 10 or 20. It will be equal to an entity. But in a functional test you'll be able to load the entity and check if the field has the good value or not after your function has been called.

Comment: alright, thanks I'll look into functional tests then. I corrected the assertEqual() code - that was a typo only in the question and not in my actual code.

Comment: Functional tests almost seem to be too much for what I need, what about kernel tests (e.g. EntityKernelTestBase)?

Comment: Kernel test should be good yep.
Either you create an entity, make your test and erase the entity
Or you use an entity already created, make your test and swap back to the previous value after your test has been called.